# Lex (flex) generates dangerous trailing context warning when using end of line match pattern `$` in rule

Tags: lex

## Cause

I was working on a shell project for my course and I wrote a rule in my lex file as follow to match a special keyword when it was entered by the user:

```
^"key_word"$ { /* Do something here */ }
```

When I compiled my lex file (using `flex -l`), it then generates the following warning at the line of this rule:

```
warning, dangerous trailing context
```

I then looked up the manual of flex, and it said the following which I think does not match the pattern I used.

> Some trailing context patterns cannot be properly matched and generate warning messages ("dangerous trailing context"). These are patterns where the ending of the first part of the rule matches the beginning of the second part, such as "zx*/xy*", where the 'x*' matches the 'x' at the beginning of the trailing context. (Note that the POSIX draft states that the text matched by such patterns is undefined.)

## Problem

From the manual, I also knew that `test$` is equivalent to `test/\n` so I created the following test lex file to do some experiment and compile it with `flex -l`:

```
%{
    int nFirstMatch;
    int nSecMatch;
    int nThirdMatch;
%}

%%

"first"/\n { nFirstMatch++; }
"second"$ { nSecMatch++; }
"third"\n { nThirdMatch++; }

%%

int yywrap(void) {
    return 1;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    yylex();
    fclose(yyin);
}
```

The output from the flex (both version 2.6.4 and 2.5.35 Apple(flex-32)) is as follow (line 10 is the second rule above):

```
eol.l:10: warning, dangerous trailing context
```

However, from the manual `test$` is equivalent to `test/\n` so they should generate the same result. Moreover, when I removed the `-l` flag (maximal compatibility with original lex), the warning was then gone.

## Question

So my question is: is this a kind of internal bug within the implementation of flex when using the `-l` flag?

Comment: Why do you want to use the `-l` flag? It causes some other very odd behaviour (like a different precedence for numeric repetition operators).

Comment: It was given in the skeleton code provided, so I took it as granted.

Comment: Usually it's a mistake, although there are maybe a handful of ancient files out there which were written according to pre-Posix lex rules which won't produce the correct result without `-l`. But certainly any new scanner should be processed without the `-l` flag (and without any of the modifications which that flag requires), even if you might be processing it with some other lex variant. That doesn't answer your question, though.

Comment: I'm pretty sure your suspicion is correct, and that it's a bug in the lex-compatibility code.  But I can't say for sure what the bug is :-( I have a feeling I ran into this many years ago and half-figured it out at the time. But it's not really that important, since, as I say, you should never use `-l`.

Comment: By the way, if you received that skeleton as part of your class's course materials, feel free to pass these comments on to your instructor. Or tell them to get in touch.